# Error building latest linux kernel within VirtualBox under 18.04.1-Ubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox, building

I am trying to build the latest Linux kernel ([GitHub](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)) using a Oracel VM and a 18.04.1-Ubuntu image.

I installed the need packages and probably even more. Here is a part of the packages I installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git fakeroot build-essential ncurses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc bison flex libelf-def kernel-package
```

The full list  can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/changes.html#changes).

I ran the following commands in the `linux` folder after cloning the repository from GitHub.

```
$ cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config

$ make menuconfig
scripts/kconfig/mconf  Kconfig
.config:1118:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for NF_CT_PROTO_GRE
.config:1923:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for NET_DEVLINK
.config:7865:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for ASHMEM
.config:8724:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for ANDROID_BINDER_IPC
.config:8725:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for ANDROID_BINDERFS


*** End of the configuration.
*** Execute 'make' to start the build or try 'make help'.
```

I save and exited `menuconfig`. And finally make leads to the following error.

```
$ make -j2
Makefile:608: include/config/auto.conf: No such file or directory
Makefile:660: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig

*** Error during sync of the configuration.

scripts/kconfig/Makefile:73: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [syncconfig] Error 1
Makefile:562: recipe for target 'syncconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [syncconfig] Error 2
Makefile:678: recipe for target 'include/config/auto.conf.cmd' failed
make: *** [include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make: *** Deleting file 'include/config/auto.conf.cmd'
```

Looks like make is expecting some additional configuration files `include/config/auto.conf`. Does anyone have a clue for me.

Thanks!

Comment: `git clean -xdf; export ARCH=...; cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config; make olddefconfig; make -j2`

Comment: Nope, not working `$ make olddefconfig
Makefile:555: arch/.../Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'arch/.../Makefile'.  Stop.`

Comment: Of course. Instead of `...` you **have to** apply the architecture you want to build for.

Comment: So I tried  the described process with `export ARCH=x86_64` which still was leading to `Makefile:608: include/config/auto.conf: No such file or directory
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig

*** Error during sync of the configuration.

`.

Comment: `export ARCH=ia64` also did not work, but I already get errors during `make olddefconfig`.

Comment: `$ make olddefconfig
./arch/ia64/scripts/check-segrel.S: Assembler messages:
./arch/ia64/scripts/check-segrel.S:2: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.rodata'
./arch/ia64/scripts/check-segrel.S:3: Error: no such instruction: `data4 @segrel(start)'
objdump: '/tmp/out8220': No such file
objdump: section '.rodata' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
./arch/ia64/scripts/toolchain-flags: 20: [: !=: unexpected operator
./arch/ia64/scripts/check-text-align.S: Assembler messages:`

Answer (score 4):

Trying to compile kernel 5.6.3 as non-root, I ran into this exact problem.
Running the suggestion from Oandiy's comment

```
git clean -xdf
```

revealed that I had files in my source tree that were owned by root and could not be deleted. Looking in my history I found,

```
sudo make localmodconfig  # DO NOT DO THIS
```

which had installed files, as root, in `include/config/*` and `include/generated/autoconf.h`.

To see if you have the same problem, run

```
sudo find . -uid 0
```

or just look at the error messages of `git clean -xdf` (there shouldn't be any).

After deleting all files and directories owned by root, I recovered from this deadlock with:

```
unset ARCH
cp .config ../config.backup  # If you still have this.
git clean -xdf               # No errors (this also deletes .config)
cp ../config.backup .config  # Or generate a new one *).
make olddefconfig            # Printed at the end: 'No change to .config'
```

Note that I needed to clear ARCH from my environment.

After this I went on as usual,

```
VERSION=5.6.3                # I have checked out tag v5.6.3 **)
FLAVOUR=lowlatlocxhci        # Or whatever you want to call your kernel.
make -j8 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-$FLAVOUR
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-headers-$VERSION-${FLAVOUR}_$VERSION-$FLAVOUR-1_amd64.deb ../linux-image-$VERSION-${FLAVOUR}_$VERSION-${FLAVOUR}-1_amd64.deb
```

The last command fails to compile virtualbox kernel modules at the moment, but I don't care about those, and those errors can be ignored (as long as you don't use virtual box).

*) The .config used was prepared by booting to a kernel with everything (ie, a dist. kernel), copying its config from /boot to the source tree and running `make localmodconfig` after making sure all kernel modules that I needed where loaded (by running those applications that cause such modules to be loaded). And finally running `make menuconfig` to turn off `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` in this kernel and to turn a few things that are normally built into the kernel into modules as well (which I needed for some reason).

**) My git tree has been prepared with:

```
VERSION=5.6.3
FLAVOUR=lowlatlocxhci
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git linux-$VERSION-$FLAVOUR-$VERSION-$FLAVOUR
cd linux-$VERSION-$FLAVOUR-$VERSION-$FLAVOUR
git checkout -b test_$FLAVOUR v$VERSION
# Make manual changes here, and commit as usual.
```

Answer (score 0):

issues like these are generally due to file persmission, i compile kernel as non root,
and before compiling, from the linux source dir (generally /usr/src/linux)

```
"chown -R myuser:myuser *"
```